# Form_for building multiple relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, form-for

Currently I have three models, a User, which has_many Projects, and the Projects has_many Parts.  I'm currently building a relationship model(Part_Item) between the User and the Parts.

Simplified Models:

```
class User
   has_many :projects
   has_many :part_items
end

class Project
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :parts, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end

class Part
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :part_items
end

class PartItem
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :part
end
```

On the projects page a User will be able to push a I Made It button which will create the relationship between the User and Parts.  This is so a User can see which parts he has already used.  If there was only one part I could write the following:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.part_items.build(part_id: @part.id), remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :part_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "I Made It", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't work for the many parts, which are a nested attribute of the project.

***Questions***:
1. How do I obtain a hash of just the part items in the form?  I tried:

```
<%= @project.parts.each do |part| %>
    <div><%= hidden_field_tag :part_id, part.id %></div>
<% end %>
```

but this only grabs the last part_id.

**2.** Should I just have a create method in my PartItem controller?  Any advice/direction in how I should set up my actions in the PartItem controller would be appreciated.  Currently I only have:

```
def create
    @part = Part.find(params[:part_id])
    current_user.save_part!(@part)
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

Which works for saving one part, but won't work for saving multiple parts.

Comment: update it to <%= f.hidden_field :part_id, part.id %>

Comment: if your application is in live  mode give url for that so it will be easy to know what really you are trying to do

Comment: @NitinJ updated it to <%= hidden_field_tag :part_id, part.id %> f.hidden_field gives an error.  This only grabs the last part_id however.  It isn't in live mode, basically I have a project with parts as a nested attribute.  I want to collect the part_ids in a form and submit to the PartItem controller so I can make a relationship between the user and the parts.

Comment: my skype handle is nitinjain2021. ping me there if you failed to solve that . i would love to sort that out . i would be available on that after one hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was thinking about this all the wrong way, and a good nights sleep cleared everything up.

I wanted to have a button that makes a relationship between the User and the Parts through a button on the Project page.  My first thought was to make a form that would gather all the part.id's into a hash and submit it to a controller where I would separate them and individual save the relation.

**My Solution:**

The parts are a nested attribute of the project.  So instead I made a form to just submit the project.id to the controller.  Then I can get all the parts from the nested attribute relationship and make the new relation.  So now my form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([current_user.part_items.build]) do |f| %>
    <div><%= hidden_field_tag :project_id, @project.id %></div>
    <%= f.submit "I Made This!", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

And the controller create action looks like this:

```
def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @project.parts.each do |part|
        @part = part.id
        current_user.save_part!(part)   
    end

end
```

And everything now works.